# Return a object from fs.readFile in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am trying to return jsonObj below and it is not returning. Help would be appreciated. Here fileName is the path of the file which I need to read. And again, I need to return jsonObj. So I can access it outside fs.readFile function.``
Here is the code

```
return fs.readFile(fileName, 'utf-8', (err, fileContent) => {
  if(err) {
     console.log(err); // Do something to handle the error or just throw it
     throw new Error(err);
  }
  let jsonObj = csvjson.toObject(fileContent);
  console.log(jsonObj)
  return jsonObj
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In Node you don't `return` from a callback function, that gets discarded and ignored. You must either use Promises, possibly in conjunction with `async`/`await`, or you must accept a callback function of your own.

This is the founding principle of asynchronous code:

```
// The fs.readFile() function executes immediately
fs.readFile(..., (err, ...) => {
   // This code runs in the distant future, like imagine ten years from now
   // from the perspective of the computer.
});

// JavaScript continues here immediately.
```

The `readFile` function does not return anything in particular, the inner function has not yet been run. It's also worth noting that throwing exceptions in there is pointless, don't do it.

To chain:

```
function getData(fileName, cb) {
  fs.readFileName(fileName, 'utf-8', (err, fileContent) => {
    if (err) {
      // Back-propagate the error
      return cb(err);
    }

    // Engage the callback function with the data
    cb(null, csvjson.toObject(fileContent));
  }
}
```

Note that this code is a lot less convoluted and messy if you use promises instead.

Comment: Then how would I use the jsonObj(or in this case cb) to another function?